# How can I disable the low disk space warning on a single drive in Windows 8?

Tags: disk-space, windows-8

Id like to disable the low disk space warning, ideally for a single drive in Windows 8.

My gut feeling is that is it will be an all or nothing change.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the low space threshold? 10%? I can lower the pagefile size as not to trigger the warning.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/11/17/10092277.aspx

Comment: The key name is `NoLowDiskSpaceChecks` not `NoLowDiscSpaceChecks`.

Comment: Since you're running low on space I thought I would mention `disk cleanup` which can blast off a big chuck of space if you hit the Clean Up System files button and delete everything.

Answer (score 16):

The documented method of disabling the low disk-space warning is described in [this KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/free-up-drive-space-in-windows-85529ccb-c365-490d-b548-831022bc9b32):

> 1. Start > Run > Regedit > OK
> 2. Now navigate to the following location
>    `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`
> 3. Right Click on the blank area of the right pane of the registry editor and create a new DWORD Value by selecting New > DWORD Value.
> 4. Name this newly created DWORD Value -"NoLowDiskSpaceChecks"
> 5. Now double-click on the new DWORD and assign it the value 1.
> 6. Close the registry editor and restart the system.

This is a per-user setting and cannot be set on disk-by-disk basis.

The way that Windows 7 and earlier chose whether or not to display this warning for a drive is described by Raymond Chen [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101117-00/?p=12263), however it might be different for Windows 8.

Comment: Small note, you can deploy the reg key with GPO's to several users.

Comment: Boo.  I also need it per disk.  It's totally fine with me if one particular data drive fills up (software handles expiring out stuff as needed to clear just enough space on the fly).  Having a flag popped up about it all the time is really annoying.

Answer (score 4):

You can disable the low disk space notification for all users of the computer as follows:

1. Run `regedit` to open Registry Editor
2. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`
3. Create a new DWORD value named **NoLowDiskSpaceChecks** and set its data to `1`

Tested on Windows 7 and Server 2008/R2

Answer (score 3):

I tried all the above suggestions and only one worked. The drive that is always popping up the low disk space message is the same drive I have my swap file on.

What Finally worked for my windows 7 enterprise it to set the swap file to a fixed length at about 300 MB less than the total space of the drive. Windows starts complaining about low disk space when 200 MB or less remain.

I hope this helps some one.

One thing to note is low disk space can suspend System Restore on that disk. 
If any disk is suspended, System Restore is suspended on all disks. So no System Restore points will be created. see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300044 for more information

Comment: Do You know, does this apply to newer Windows versions too? The article You refer to mentions Win XP.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the problem on a drive I set up for Window's page file (so it would not be included in a system backup).  I tried to use the as much of the drive as I could; but I started getting the errors.  My solution was simply to reduce the size of the allocated page file by 200MB.  Not that big a deal relative to the full 6GB of the drive.

Comment: Decent backup software won't include the page file...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Open Regedit
2. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem`
3. Create a new `DWORD` called `DisableLowDiskSpaceBroadcast` and set its value to a number based on the drive you want to disable notifications for:

```
Drive Letter   Data Value  

A                      1  
B                      2  
C                      4  
D                      8  
E                     16  
F                     32
G                     64
H                    128
I                    256
J                    512
K                   1024
L                   2048
M                   4096
N                   8192
O                  16384
P                  32768
Q                  65536
R                 131072
S                 262144
T                 524288
U                1048576
V                2097152
W                4194304
X                8388608
Y               16777216
Z               33554432
```

> NOTE: If you want to disable the error message for more than one drive, you can add the data values of the drives located in the table, and then set the data value of the `DisableLowDiskSpaceBroadcast` value using the sum of the data values that you added. For example, drive `E` has a value of `16` and drive `G` has a value of `64`. These two data values added together equal 80. To disable the low disk space notification for drive `E` and drive `G`, set the data value of the `DisableLowDiskSpaceBroadcast` value to `80`.

Soruce: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/188074

Comment: Downvoted. I cannot get this method to work under Windows 7, and I'm pretty sure this would be the case under Windows 8 as well. The cited source only mentions Windows 98, and even gives a warning that it doesn't work with my operating system (as detected by the page.)

Answer (score 0):

**Theory**: Microsoft says: DisableLowDiskSpaceBroadcast is for disabling the warning when copying files to a disk ONLY. So this is not the warning that appears in the tray, but the window that recommends cleaning the disk as soon as copying is about to fail. This key can be set for individual disks. Microsoft describes it for Windows 7 only.

**Practical**: With Windows 8, I found this key will not disable the tray warning for my backup medium. So the posting of Darth Android is proven to be wrong, while Microsoft might be right.

`NoLowDiskSpaceChecks` disables the warning in the tray. This can be set for a user, not for a single disk. This key is said to work with Windows 7+8.

Comment: The key name is `NoLowDiskSpaceChecks`; with "Disk" instead of "Disc"

Answer (score 0):

Or you can turn of and hide the notification in the properties of the taskbar. right click the taskbar and select properties and then show hide notifications and hide it.