# How to disable Low disk space for ReadyBoost dedicated drives on Windows 8.1?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, readyboost

I've enabled a disk partition of around 8 GB to be dedicated for [ReadyBoost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReadyBoost).

[image: Setup screen for ReadyBoost]

Windows keep warning me about that disk running out of space (*Low Disk Space*).

[image: The dedicated disk is full]

How do I turn off that warning for THAT disk and ONLY that disk.

I DO want that warning, I do not want it for that disk I specifically instructed windows to completely fill.

I find it absurd that a Windows feature meant to completely fill a disk cause an annoying warning that you can't disable.

Comment: As stated in this answer it cannot be disabled on a single drive....http://superuser.com/a/495433/40928

Comment: is this for real? ReadyBoost has an option to fill the disk. It's meant to fill it.... so this is a bug?

Comment: Yes, welcome to the world of Microsoft....

Comment: Also the question you mark as duplicated has no answer and it has been closed for spam.

Comment: Its not closed its protected by the community. It has an answer, it is not possible.

Comment: @DanieleSegato The linked duplicate question has **6** answers.  What question are you looking at?

Comment: none is accepted. also i'm specifically asking about ReadyBoost while the other question ask for a random disk. maybe there's something for readyboost that is bot possible otherwise